# 10 _dyid_start - thread crash after migrating to Swift 4

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode9, swift4

After upgrading to Xcode 9 & updating my frameworks to swift 4 using cocoapods, whenever I try launching the app on the simulator, it crashes at :

> 0 _abort_using_payload
>
> 10 _dyid_start

without any error message (see images attached). 
I tried to clean & rebuild the project, and reset the simulator but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea of how could I solve this problem, or how could I debug this precisely ? 
Thanks

[image][image]

Comment: Did your check that all pods correctly work on xcode 9?

Comment: yes everything was moved to swift 4 if should work fine with Xcode 9

Comment: Did you clean derived data?

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot.
You can provide it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue on my machine by cleaning derived data.

To do so, close Xcode, open a terminal & run :

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Or go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data, clear its content & restart Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

just go to xcode preferences-> locations-> derived data.
close xcode and delete all datas in derived folder. then open again xcode,